# Create a view of views?

Tags: views

I love Drupal views and tags but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do this.

We have several online seminars with multiple sessions in each.

For example:  Refocusing on Family part 1, Refocusing on Family part 2, True Womanhood part 1, etc.

For each of these articles I have a view created that will return all the articles in that category.

For example, when you click on Refocusing on Family you get a page with teasers and links for:

- Refocusing on Family part 1
- Refocusing on Family part 2
- etc.

What I would like to do is create a new view (something like "Life Academy" for example) that had a description and link to each of the top level views (which, in turn, link to the articles).

So the user would go to the Life Academy page and see links and descriptions for Refocusing on Family, True Womanhood, and any future seminar groups.  Clicking on these links will then take you to the view page (with links to the articles) for the appropriate group.

What I want to avoid is having to manually update the page every time a new seminar category is added.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you just group the results by a field in views?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was ultimately able to achieve this by using Display Suite.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want a taxonomy term view. Then output the name field and and use the Rewrite Results, "Output this field as a link". You'll want to make the links for the other view predictable by using arguments like TID. Then you can set your link to use tokens like seminar/tid. I think you can use term name as well with a little bit of magic on the contextual filter.

If you just want to display all categories and seminars on the same page, create a view that outputs seminars and add the taxonomy term field. Then group by the term.